# How to achieve magnifying square effect for D3 charts?

Tags: d3.js, zooming, magnification

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/VR8Xn/). Magnifying on hover works well for text and images, but I would like to have the same effect for the chart.

[image]

I would like the solution, if possible, to be applicable to any `D3` SVG-based chart.

The example uses jquery plugin AnythingZoomer, it looked to me as a good starting point, however, you don't need to stick to it, you can use anything else if you wish.

I am aware of [D3 fisheye pluging](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/fisheye), this is related, but not quite what I want.

Comment: And to clarify...the D3 fisheye plugin is not quite what you want because of the distortion effect associated with it?

Comment: Correct, I want just a square. Distortion makes me dizzy. :)

Comment: https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingZoomer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by not explicitly declaring `width` and `height` in the SVG (which is overwritten by CSS anyway), using the [`viewBox` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute), and then allowing AnythingZoom to `clone` the content of your original chart.

**Demo (Fragile):** <s>http://jsfiddle.net/H9psX/</s> http://jsfiddle.net/H9psX/38/

**Changes**

```
var svg = d3.select("#small-chart").append("svg")
//    .attr("width", diameter + 300)
//    .attr("height", diameter)
    .attr('viewBox', "0 0 " + 225 + " " + 225);

// ...

$("#zoom3").anythingZoomer({
    clone: true
});
```

**Separation of concerns**

Since you are drawing in SVG using D3 (where you need to know the `width` and `height` for the pack layout) and using a jquery plugin which zooms by setting classes and absolute positioning, you have to share the coordinates (the `225px` magic number) in CSS and in JS.

Ideally, you would want to keep the magic number at only one place. To do that you can declare the value only in CSS and then read them in your JS after creating your SVG element.

Comment: Neat!  I'll have to remember that little utility.

Comment: @gaitat Updated the demo.

Comment: @musically_ut, could you please look into this for me, problem zoom box never shows any content in it, here is the plunker, any help is much appreciated https://plnkr.co/edit/KfpgMFFGHdyAbC5rQAeL?p=preview